# Firebase disk persistence error : Modifications to Config objects must occur before they are in use

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app using Firebase as backend.I am trying to implement disk persistence provided by Firebase but my app crashes when i restart the app. The document says to write `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true)` to write prior to any firebase reference, I did so but its not working.

Here is portion of my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        firebase = new Firebase(getString(R.string.firebase_url));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //remaining code
}
```

Log output:

```
Caused by: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Modifications to Config objects must occur before they are in use
        at com.firebase.client.core.Context.assertUnfrozen(Context.java:124)
        at com.firebase.client.Config.setPersistenceEnabled(Config.java:155)
        at activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:148)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
```

Comment: Call setPersistenceEnabled() before setAndroidContext().

Comment: Its not working bro. I tried to figure out and found just one clue : When the application don't stick in the cache memory then restarting the app doesn't crash the app. So I cleared the cache memory manually and the app works fine. But this is not the right solution. Any other idea???

Comment: Its working, your sample app(https://github.com/firebase/AndroidDrawing) helped me figure out the problem :).

Answer (score 9):

Got it! The problem was `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` 
and `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` are to be declared only once per application, as the documentation says (https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/).

So, the above mentioned two statements are to be included in the onCreate() of application java file and not inside activity java file. Also they should be included before creating any firebase object. That solves the problem :).

Comment: An application java file is a child of class Application. It means you have to create a class that extends Application class.Then include the statement Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true) inside the onCreate().Do not forget to do the manifest entry.

Comment: also, it should be added before making any ref initialisation.

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing the similar problem and finally solved the problem, just check if the `isPersistenceEnabled` is false and then only set the persistence. Do this on your `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Firebase.getDefaultConfig().isPersistenceEnabled() == false)
        Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

}

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thanks @Surendra